# Plain text to json format into sublime text

Tags: json, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How can I convert this plain text that is recognized as json format and see json format into sublime text.

```
[{ "page": 1, "paragraph": 1, "text1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame", "text2": "er bibendum at, quis tempor purus euism"}, {"page": 1, "paragraph": 2, "text1": "uismod suspe", "text2": "Mattis euismod nec p"}, { "page": 1, "paragraph": 3, "text1": "venenatis litora cum nibh arcu porta", "text2": "augue tempor"}]
```

Any idea to help me????

Comment: Have you tried this? https://blog.adriaan.io/sublime-pretty-json.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Prettify/Minify/Query/Goto/Validate/Lint JSON plugin for Sublime  Text 2 & 3**

From the github documentation [Sublime Text 3 pretty JSON](https://blog.adriaan.io/sublime-pretty-json.html)

> ##### Installation
>
> Install this sublime text 2/3 package via Package Control search for
> package: "Pretty JSON" or manually install cd 
> (for example on Mac it is ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime
> Text\ 2/Packages or ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text
> 3/Packages) git clone [SublimePrettyJson.git](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson.git)
>
> ##### Usage
>
> To prettify JSON, make selection of json (or else it will try to use
> full view buffer) and press keys:
>
> Linux: ctrl+alt+j
>
> Windows: ctrl+alt+j
>
> OS X: cmd+ctrl+j
>
> or through Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P find "Pretty JSON: Format
> (Pretty Print) JSON" (you can search for part of it like 'pretty
> format')
>
> If selection is empty and configuration entry
> use_entire_file_if_no_selection is true, tries to prettify whole file
>
> If JSON is not valid it will be displayed in status bar of Sublime
> Text
>
> ##### Validate JSON
>
> Using Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P find "Pretty JSON: Validate" (you
> can search for partial string 'validate') this will validate selection
> or full file and will show in dialog if it's valid or invalid. In case
> of found errors view will jump to error and will highlight it
>
> ##### Compress / Minify JSON
>
> Using Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P find "Pretty JSON: Minify
> (compress) JSON" (you can search for part of it like 'json minify')
> this will make selection or full buffer as single line JSON which
> later you can use in command lines (curl/httpie) or somewhere else...
>
> To map a key combination like Ctrl+Alt+M to the Minify command, you
> can add a setting like this to your .sublime-keymap file (eg:
> Packages/User/Default (Windows).sublime-keymap):
>
> { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+m" ], "command": "un_pretty_json" }
>
> ##### Convert JSON to XML
>
> Using Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P search fo "Pretty JSON: JSON 2 XML"
> (you can search for part of it like '2XML') this will convert your
> selected JSON of full buffer to XML and replace syntax and buffer to
> XML output
>
> ##### ./jQ query/filter usage
>
> If on your machine "./jq" tool is available with ctrl+atl+shift+j you
> can run against your json. output will be opened in new view so you
> can once again apply jq on new buffer
>
> You can find instructions of tool here:
>
> [jQ lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
>
> ##### Default configuration
>
> use_entire_file_if_no_selection - true
>
> indent - 2 int used for how many spaces to use for indent, replace it
> with value "\t" and tabs will be used instead
>
> sort_keys - false
>
> ensure_ascii - false
>
> line_separator - ","
>
> value_separator - ": " value separator in config, so if you need to
> get rid of extra space you can remove it with this param
>
> keep_arrays_single_line - false if we need to re-structure arrays and
> make them single-line
>
> max_arrays_line_length - 120 if array for example '["a", "b", 123213,
> ....]' length will reach max it will be kept multi-line (for beauty)
>
> pretty_on_save - false do we need to automatically Pretty JSON on save
>
> validate_on_save - true do we need validate JSON files on each save
>
> ##### Using tabs for indentation
>
> You can change configuration key indent to string value "\t" or any
> other string
>
> "indent" : "\t", Be sure "Indent Using Spaces" is unchecked otherwise
> you will not see effect and ST2/3 will convert it back to spaces